# How to convert factors in a data frame to prespecified colour names in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate heatmaps for gene expression data which also have columns representing clinical data as can be seen here: https://www.biostars.org/p/18211/

My problem is, both heatmap.plus and heatmap.3 require that the matrix specifying the colours in the heatmap actually be written as colour names. They won't take normal factors in a column and convert them to colours.

This is what my data frame "df" looks like:

```
sample_name     gender     chemotherapy     clinical_subtype
sample_01       M          alk              1
sample_02       F          tmz              2
sample_03       M          rad              2
sample_04       M          rad.tmz          4
sample_05       F          tmz              3
```

I can generate a data frame of the levels of each factor matched to a specific colour using the following code:

```
gender_colors <- with(df, data.frame(row.names = levels(gender), color = brewer.pal(nlevels(gender), name = 'Set1')))
```

Which looks like the following (with 3 colours because of missing samples):

```
  color
  #66C2A5
F #FC8D62
M #8DA0CB
```

Is there any way to use this data frame to index the original factors, replacing them with their corresponding colour so that my original frame would look something like the following?

```
sample_name     gender     chemotherapy     clinical_subtype
sample_01       #8DA0CB    #FC8D62          #FDAE61
sample_02       #FC8D62    #66C2A5          #FFFFBF
sample_03       #8DA0CB    #C2294A          #FFFFBF
sample_04       #8DA0CB    #FA9856          #A6D96A
sample_05       #FC8D62    #66C2A5          #1A9641
```

If there is an easier way to do this that doesn't require me to generate the intermediate factor level matched data frame to specific colours that would probably be a lot easier, but any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
      color
1     #D7191C
2     #FDAE61
3     #FFFFBF
4     #A6D96A
5     #1A9641
```

Comment: Whence are the colors for `chemotherapy` and `clinical_subtype`?

Comment: They are in separate data frames that look exactly like the one for gender (see above)

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `merge()` to join the colors for the 3 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend keeping it simple and using `merge()` to join the various color data frames onto your main `df` data frame.  For example, to join the gender `color` data frame to `df` you can use this:

```
color.gender <- data.frame(gender=c("", "F", "M"),
                           color=c("#66C2A5", "#FC8D62", "#8DA0CB"))
df <- merge(df, color.gender, by="gender")
```

This would leave `df` looking like the following:

```
sample_name     gender     chemotherapy     clinical_subtype     color.gender
sample_01       M          alk              1                    #8DA0CB
sample_02       F          tmz              2                    #FC8D62
sample_03       M          rad              2                    #8DA0CB
sample_04       M          rad.tmz          4                    #8DA0CB
sample_05       F          tmz              3                    #FC8D62
```

If you are restricted to a certain number of columns or names, you can easily rework the data frame.

Comment: Yeah actually that worked really well. I think I was trying to over-complicate the issue! Thank you.